# Grails, gorm. Find child by parent and parent by child

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For example, I've parent class Author:

```
class Author {    
    String name
    static hasMany = [
         fiction: Book, 
         nonFiction: Book
    ]
}
```

and a child class Book:

```
class Book {    
    String title
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

I've done some records to Author using:

```
def fictBook = new Book(title: "IT")
def nonFictBook = new Book(title: "On Writing: A Memoir of the Craft")
def a = new Author(name: "Stephen King")
             .addToFiction(fictBook)
             .addToNonFiction(nonFictBook)
             .save()
```

How can I found child-class record by parent and parent-class record by child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, this is not the best way to model your data. I would do it like this.

```
class Author {    
  String name
  static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
  String title
  BookTypes bookType
  static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}

enum BookTypes {
  FICTION,
  NON_FICTION
}
```

Then, you can do lookups like

```
def author = Author.get(1)
def nonFictionByAuthor = Book.findAllByAuthorAndBookType(author, BookTypes.NON_FICTION)
```

You could also just do something like this...

```
def author = Author.get(1)
def fictionBooks = author.books.findAll { it.bookType == BookTypes.FICTION }
```

And then inversely:

```
def fictionBook = Book.findByTitleAndBookType('Title001', BookTypes.FICTION)
```